# Convert from IObservable<byte> to Stream?

Tags: .net, performance, stream, observable, system.reactive

I was looking to convert from `IObservable<byte>` to `Stream` and came up with this code that uses `System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe`.

```cs
public static Stream ToStream(this IObservable<byte> observable, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    var pipe = new System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe();

    var reader = pipe.Reader;
    var writer = pipe.Writer;

    observable
        .Buffer(bufferSize)
        .Select(buffer => Observable.FromAsync(async () => await writer.WriteAsync(buffer.ToArray())))
        .Concat()
        .Subscribe(_ => { }, onCompleted: () => { writer.Complete(); }, onError: exception => writer.Complete(exception));

    return reader.AsStream();
}
```

I've tried to write the resulting Stream to disk and the **performance is terrible** (under 10 MB/s). I'm starting to think that something is wrong. I hope someone can shed light to this and provide a better method to proxy observable of byte to Stream.

Comment: `IObservable<byte>` is an odd chocie to begin with - what's the backstory here?

Comment: I guess it’s better than IObservable<bit>. But this does sound like an XY problem.

Comment: @Shlomo I'm looking for elegance. Call me idealistic.

Comment: Your question isn’t looking for elegance though, it’s looking for performance. At a practical level, you’re necessitating multiple function calls, stack operations for each individual byte passed through.

Comment: @Shlomo I'm looking for both. If not possible, I will fall back to Stream. I'd like to stick to Observable if it's possible without having sluggish performance. Thanks for your time in any case :)

Comment: I still don’t know the use case, but if streams are your alternative, you could look at  IObservable<byte[]>.